# wpf datagrid focus on the selectemItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

I programmatically selectItem in a datagrid.
The problem is though that i have to manually scroll down to selectItem. I need to do this automatically. 
so far I have tried many thing and nothing works for me...

DataGrid:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="coreServiceLogDataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentCoreServiceLogDataItem,Source={StaticResource synchronizer}, Mode=TwoWay}"
              GotFocus="coreServiceLogDataGrid_GotFocus_1"
              Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=dataGridStyle}"
              ...>
              ...
    </DataGrid>
```

and code behind for `GotFocus`:

```
        private void coreServiceLogDataGrid_GotFocus_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {
          if (coreServiceLogDataGrid.SelectedItem != null) {
            coreServiceLogDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(coreServiceLogDataGrid.SelectedItem);
          }
         }
```

Comment: Have you verified that the event `GotFocus` actually fires and  `coreServiceLogDataGrid.SelectedItem` is not null?

Comment: @AbZy I have update the code, but it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue in the past. I've done this for the `DataGridRow` but it is based on an attached behavior for the `TreeViewItem` found on this [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF).

Here is the code for the `code-behind`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Exposes attached behaviors that can be
/// applied to DataGridRow objects.
/// </summary>
public static class DataGridRowBehavior
{
    #region IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected

    public static bool GetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(DataGridRow dataGridRow)
    {
        return (bool)dataGridRow.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(
      DataGridRow dataGridRow, bool value)
    {
        dataGridRow.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DataGridRowBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));

    static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(
      DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow item = depObj as DataGridRow;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnDataGridRowSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OnDataGridRowSelected;
    }

    static void OnDataGridRowSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only react to the Selected event raised by the TreeViewItem
        // whose IsSelected property was modified. Ignore all ancestors
        // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired.
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;

        DataGridRow item = e.OriginalSource as DataGridRow;
        if (item != null)
            item.BringIntoView();
    }

    #endregion // IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected
}
```

And in your `XAML`, place this code between your tags for the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="uc:DataGridRowBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
/// note: uc is a namespace I have defined for where the DataGridRowBehavior class is located
```

Additional comment: I have the `SelectionUnit` set to `FullRow` and `SelectionMode` set to `Single`. I'm not sure if changing those properties will affect whether or not this will work.